# Force IntelliJ IDEA to use junit4 to run 'All Tests'

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit, intellij-plugin

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.5 (Community Edition) and all my test cases are against Junit 4 and it's was working fine. Recently I am getting errors like these...

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/launcher/TestExecutionListener

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener
```

I got to know that Junit 5 expects these classes but my code is not Junit-5-ready. I cannot migrate to JUnit 5 as I think this can be handled at IDE level. Also, the test cases work fine with `mvn` commands outside the IDE using java 8.

I found IDE running this command to run 'All Tests'

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
 -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:54748,suspend=y,server=n
 -ea
 -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576
 -javaagent:/Library/Caches/IdeaIC2019.3/captureAgent/debugger-agent.jar
 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
 -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/junit/lib/junit5-rt.jar:..."
 -ideVersion5
 -junit5 @w@/private/var/folders/qr/mm80vkf55_qct4dffc662nhcz2kj03/T/idea_working_dirs_junit.tmp @/private/var/folders/qr/mm80vkf55_qct4dffc662nhcz2kj03/T/idea_junit.tmp
 -socket54747
```

Can I force IntelliJ to run test cases using JUnit 4 only?

FYI: I am using maven and bundled JUnit plugin with Intellij IDEA 2019.3.5 (Community Edition)

Comment: How are you running your test cases?

Comment: By right-clicking on the module in the project tree and selecting Run 'All Tests'

Comment: I don't think, there is such settings in intelij because intelij picks the junit engine by itself, seems its not picking in your case, check if you have mix of junit 5 and junit 4 annotations

Comment: Is the issue reproduced for you with the latest IntelliJ IDEA version? https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/

Comment: do you use maven/gradle to builld the application outside intellij or only use IntelliJ?

Comment: I use maven outside IntelliJ and it works fine

Comment: yes. I faced this issue with the latest IntelliJ IDEA too... IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1 (CE)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that IntelliJ still works perfectly fine with JUnit 4, so I assume this is a problem with your project setup. Can you share the project? And did you try deleting all IntelliJ configuration from it and reimporting it?

Comment: Yes. I too think might be a project issue (more of a single module issue) but I not sure which configuration to change. Also, I tried resetting the IntelliJ configuration to default settings and imported the project freshly from a different directory and it did not work